# mysql trigger work not always

Tags: mysql, triggers

I try to insert trigger to mysql table of 3Th party windows program.
In original it was seample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `sent` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `fast` (`dt`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

My goal is mark a data, inserted from my php scripts. For this purpose i create 2 new field in table.

```
`sent` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`sourceColumn` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

sent - for marking is data alredy used or not, and sourceColumn - to mark insertion reason.

sometimes i need to set send=99 in ponts, are inserted of 3Th party windows program. For this i create  trigger:

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`%`
TRIGGER `abc`.`data`
BEFORE INSERT ON `abc`.`data`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS (select ID FROM OrigLock where id=NEW.id AND  NEW.dt between date_start AND date_stop) ) THEN
SET NEW.sent=99;
END IF;
END
$$
```

This work fine, but some times approximaly 1 of 1000 in table exist rows, where dt inside interval date_start AND date_stop and sent=NULL and sourceColumn=NULL, i.e. looks like rows inserted Windows programm without trigger. 
Have any ideas on how data can get to the table, without processing the trigger?

OrigLock Structure:

```
enter code here

CREATE TABLE `OrigLock` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DataID1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DataID2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_stop` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`DataID1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=450 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you please post the `INSERT` statement and some sample data in `OrigLock` when this trigger does not work? The problem has to be at least reproducible in order for you or everyone to solve.

Comment: I can't post INSERT, because it from 3Th party windowsprogram (not my program) **bold** 
id--DataID1--DataID2---date_start---_date_stop
445 92 79 2014-01-13 22:00:00 2014-01-14 02:57:05
446 92 78 2014-01-13 22:00:00 2014-01-14 02:57:05

Comment: Please post the exact table schema for `OrigLock` like you did for `data`. Specifically what is the exact data type for `date_start` and `date_stop`?

Comment: I can't post INSERT, because it from 3Th party windowsprogram (not my program) **OrigLock**
id DataID1 DataID2 date_start  date_stop
445 92 79 2014-01-13 22:00:00 2014-01-14 02:57:05
446 92 78 2014-01-13 22:00:00 2014-01-14 02:57:05

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21108957/edit) your question and put it there in a formatted way. In comments it's undecipherable.

Comment: In thi case (insert in other table) use better an AFTER insert trigger.